# Force spider to stop in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have 20 spiders in one project, each spider has different task and URL to crawl ( but data are similar and I'm using shared `items.py` and `pipelines.py` for all of them), by the way in my pipelines class I want if some conditions satisfied that specified spider stop crawl.
I've testing

```
  raise DropItem("terminated by me")
```

and

```
 raise CloseSpider('terminate by me')
```

but both of them just stop the current running of spider and next_page url still crawling !!!

part of my **pipelines.py**

```
class MongoDBPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        connection = pymongo.MongoClient(
            settings['MONGODB_SERVER'],
            settings['MONGODB_PORT']
        )
        db = connection[settings['MONGODB_DB']]
        self.collection = db[settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION']]

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        raise CloseSpider('terminateby')
        raise DropItem("terminateby")

        valid = True
        for data in item:
            if not data:
                valid = False
                raise DropItem("Missing {0}!".format(data))
        if valid:
            self.collection.insert(dict(item))
            log.msg("Items added to MongoDB database!",
                    level=log.DEBUG, spider=spider)
        return item
```

and my spider

```
import scrapy
import json
from Maio.items import MaioItem



class ZhilevanSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'tehran'
    allowed_domains = []
    start_urls = ['https://search.Maio.io/json/']
    place_code = str(1);

    def start_requests(self):

        request_body = {
                "id": 2,
                "jsonrpc": "2.0",
                "method": "getlist",
                "params": [[["myitem", 0, [self.place_code]]], next_pdate]
        }
        # for body in request_body:
        #     request_body = body

        request_body = json.dumps(request_body)
        print(request_body)
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url='https://search.Maio.io/json/',
            method="POST",
            body=request_body,
            callback = self.parse,
            headers={'Content-type' : 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'}
        )

    def parse(self, response):

        print(response)
        # print(response.body.decode('utf-8'))
        input = (response.body.decode('utf-8'))
        result = json.loads(input)
        # for key,item in result["result"]:
        #     print(key)
        next_pdate = result["result"]["last_post_date"];
        print(result["result"]["last_post_date"])
        for item in result["result"]["post_list"]:
            print("title : {0}".format(item["title"]))
            ads = MaioItem()
            ads['title'] = item["title"]
            ads['desc'] = item["desc"]
        yield ads
        if(next_pdate):
            request_body = {
                "id": 2,
                "jsonrpc": "2.0",
                "method": "getlist",
                "params": [[["myitem", 0, [self.place_code]]], next_pdate]
            }

            request_body = json.dumps(request_body)
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url='https://search.Maio.io/json/',
                method="POST",
                body=request_body,
                callback=self.parse,
                headers={'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}
            )
```

**update **

even I put `sys.exit("SHUT DOWN EVERYTHING!")` in the pipeline but next page still run .

I see the following log in every page running

```
sys.exit("SHUT DOWN EVERYTHING!")
SystemExit: SHUT DOWN EVERYTHING!
```

Comment: `CloseSpider()` will still process the requests that are queued, if you want to terminate immediately then implement something like killing the process ID of your scraper twice ...

Comment: @Umair thanks for your attention, but I don't want to kill others spiders which concurrently running, is it possible? provide your idea as an answer plz

Comment: No matter you are using shared pipeline, each of your spider will have a different Process ID in your server (assuming you are on Linux) ... Send `KILL PROCESS_ID` once and your particular spider will finish after executing pending requests, send `KILL PROCESS_ID` twice and it will terminate immediately. I don't see any other way to terminate spider wihtout being finishing all pending requests.

Comment: @Umair I tired, but still no result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK then you can use CloseSpider exception.

```
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
# condition
raise CloseSpider("message")
```

Comment: look at the time of the question. :).  I can't test it because I don't remember finally how I resolved that and I'm not sure the suggested solution is working. but I'm sure I tried such basic solutions. thank you for your attention dude

Comment: this is working and recommended way to stop the spider, it may be too late to tell you but definitely not for the people who want a proper solution to this problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to stop a spider from a pipeline, you can call the `close_spider()` function of the engine.

```
class MongoDBPipeline(object):

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        spider.crawler.engine.close_spider(self, reason='finished')
```

Comment: thank you for your attention, It might work  but Stopping the spider from the Pipeline is not a good solution

Comment: @YusefMohamadi It's not a good solution in general or in your use case ?

Comment: in my case   wasn't a good solution. by the way, I can't remember how I resolved this but this may works.

Answer (score 0):

why not just use this

```
# with some condition
sys.exit("Closing the spider")
```

Comment: I mentioned it on the question ;)

```even I put sys.exit("SHUT DOWN EVERYTHING!") in the pipeline but next page still run .

I see the following log in every page running

sys.exit("SHUT DOWN EVERYTHING!")
SystemExit: SHUT DOWN EVERYTHING!```