# Raise close spider from Scrapy pipeline

Tags: python, scrapy

I need to raise CloseSpider from a Scrapy Pipeline. Either that or return some parameter from the Pipeline back to the Spider to do the raise.

For example, if the date already exists raise CloseSpider:

```
raise CloseSpider('Already been scraped:' + response.url)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Quite related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9699317/771848.

Comment: Cant call close spider from pipelines. use a hack by setting a variable in spider instance you get in a pipeline process_item function

Answer (score 3):

As from scrapy docs, CloseSpider Exception can only be raised from a callback function (by default parse function) in a Spider only. Raising it in pipeline will crash spider. To achieve the similar results from a pipeline, you can initiate a shutdown signal, that will close scrapy gracefully.

```
from scrapy.project import crawler  
crawler._signal_shutdown(9,0)
```

**Do remember ,scrapy might process already fired or even scheduled requests even after initiating shutdown signal.**

To do it from Spider, set some variable in Spider from Pipeline like this.

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    if some_condition_is_met:
        spider.close_manually = True
```

After this in the callback function of your spider , you can raise close spider exception.

```
def parse(self, response):
    if self.close_manually:
        raise CloseSpider('Already been scraped.')
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the following solution.

```
class MongoDBPipeline(object):

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    spider.crawler.engine.close_spider(self, reason='duplicate')
```

Source: [Force spider to stop in scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46749659/force-spider-to-stop-in-scrapy)

Comment: Somehow this is not working. It seems like the preferred solution to stopping a spider is to stop yielding in the parse functions