# Can't stop Scrapy from inside pipeline.py

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

So I am writing a validator for my Scrapy data and want the spider to stop crawling if the data is in an incorrect format. I am doing this in Pipeline.py.

I have already tried calling CloseSpider, close_spider and crawler._signal_shutdown(9,0) (which have been used in other tutorials but for some reason don't work in pipeline.py). I am aware that the spider does not finish straight away but all the above methods seem to yield some sort of error. Is there just a straight forward way to kill the crawler?

Comment: if you get error then why you didn't show it ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 2):

Your scraper still working because of its schedule some amount of request and `CloseSpider` was created for a graceful shutdown. It means that all request that is in progress will be canceled or done before crawler will be closed. 
Do you call `close_spider()` [in this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52499699/4900574)

Answer (score 0):

Just try below code to kill the process of spider:

```py
raise SystemExit
```