# Scrapy: How to limit number of urls scraped in SitemapSpider

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm working on a sitemap spider. This spider gets one sitemap url and scrape all urls in this sitemap. I want to limit the number of urls to 100.

I can't use `CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT` because I use XML export pipeline. 
It seems that when scrapy gets to the pagecount, it stops everything including XML generating. So the XML file is not closed etc. it's invalid.

```
class MainSpider(SitemapSpider):
    name = 'main_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['doman.com']
    sitemap_urls = ['http://doman.com/sitemap.xml']

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.sitemap_urls:
            yield Request(url, self._parse_sitemap)


    def parse(self, response):
        print u'URL: {}'.format(response.url)
        if self._is_product(response):
            URL = response.url
            ITEM_ID = self._extract_code(response)

    ...
```

Do you know what to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `SitemapSpider`, you can use `sitemap_filter`, which is a proper way to filter entries.

```
    limit = 5  # Limit to 5 entries only
    count = 0  # Entries counter

    def sitemap_filter(self, entries):
        for entry in entries:
            if self.count >= self.limit:
                continue
            self.count += 1
            yield entry
```

Answer (score 0):

Using on **return** was not enough for me, but you can combine it with the **CloseSpider**  exception :

```
# To import it :
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider


#Later to use it:
raise CloseSpider('message')
```

[I posted the whole code combining both on stackoverflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177192/how-to-crawl-a-limited-number-of-pages-from-a-site-using-scrapy/64733119#64733119)

Answer (score -1):

Why not have a `count` property on the spider initialized to 0, and the on your `parse` method you can

```
def parse(self, response):
    if self.count >= 100:
         return
    self.count += 1
    # do actual parsing here
```

Comment: I was considering this method but there is a problem that it still scrapes all urls, yes, it won't parse/export them, but the number of requests is the same i

Comment: you can just place the condition someplace else

Comment: @Milano did  you find a solution for this problem?